# How to end a program by pressing a key?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, exit

I'm learning C with MS Visual Studio C++ and I can compile and run the program but it closes when it is done, I would like to add an interaction "Press any key to exit" or similar. How can it be done? I tried using `getch();` but it didn't compile. Thanks

```
/* Inkludera filer som innehåller definitioner av de biblioteks-
   funktioner som används i programmet. Användningen av #include
   i C-program har vissa likheter med Javas import-uttryck.
*/
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


/* Definiera N_POINTS till talet 4 */
#define N_POINTS        4

/* Definiera en datastruktur Point som kan innehålla en 2-D koordinat */
typedef struct {
  double x, y;
} Point;

/* Definiera en funktion distance() som räknar ut avståndet från origo till
   en punkt. Denna funktion nyttjar Pythagoras sats och funktionen
   sqrt() från matematikbiblioteket. sqrt() beräknar kvadratroten av
   ett tal.
*/
double distance(Point p) {
  double r;
  r = sqrt(p.x*p.x + p.y*p.y);
  return r;
}

/* bubblesort() tar en vektor med punkter samt vektorns längd som
   argument och sorterar punkterna i vektorn efter deras avstånd till
   origo med största avstånd först, med hjälp av bubblesort-algoritmen.
   Denna algoritm är långsam och passar dåligt när långa vektorer
   ska sorteras; den är dock enkel att implementera och passar därför
   bra till detta exempel.
*/
void bubblesort(Point points[], int length) {
  Point swap;
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i<length-1; i++)
    for(j = i+1; j<length; j++)
      if( distance(points[i]) < distance(points[j]) ) {
        swap = points[i];
        points[i] = points[j];
        points[j] = swap;
      }
}

/* main() är den funktion där programmet börjar, precis som i ett javaprogram.
   main() ska alltid returnera ett heltal, int. */
int main(void) {

/* filename blir en vektor med 80 tecken. Teckenvektorer används i C
   för att representera strängar. */
  char filename[80];

/* points blir en vektor av Point med N_POINTS element. */
  Point points[N_POINTS];

/* FILE * är en adress till en datastruktur av typen FILE. En FILE
   används för att representera filer i C. */
  FILE *file;

  int i;

/* printf() är en funktion som skriver ut text i terminalfönstret. */
  printf("Detta program läser in %d koordinater och sorterar dem.\n",N_POINTS);
printf("Sedan skrivs koordinaterna ut på en fil.\n");

  for(i = 0; i<N_POINTS; i++) {
    printf("Ange koordinat %d (format: x y): ", i+1);

/* scanf() används för att läsa in text och tal från tangentbordet. */
    scanf("%lf %lf", &points[i].x, &points[i].y);
}

/* Sortera koordinaterna genom att anropa bubblesort-funktionen ovan. */
  bubblesort(points, N_POINTS);

  printf("Nu är punkterna sorterade.\n");
  printf("Vilken fil ska de skrivas ut på? ");
  scanf("%s", filename);

/* Öppna en fil med det namn som finns i strängen filename. */
  file = fopen(filename, "w");

/* Om file är NULL så gick det inte att öppna filen. */
  if(file == NULL) {
    printf("Det gick inte att öppna filen %s.\n", filename);
} else {
    for(i = 0; i<N_POINTS; i++)
      /* fprintf() är som printf() med skriver till en fil. */
      fprintf(file, "Koordinat %2d: %10.3lf %10.3lf\n",
i+1, points[i].x, points[i].y);

/* När punkterna är skrivna på filen så ska den stängas. */
    fclose(file);

    printf("Nu är koordinaterna utskrivna på filen %s.\n", filename);
printf("För att se innehållet i filen kör kommandot: more %s\n", filename);
}

/* main() ska returnera 0 (noll) om programmet inte råkade ut för något
   fel. Det borde kanske ha returnerat 1 (ett) om det inte gick att
   öppna filen, eller frågat om ett annat filnamn, men det får bli en
   övning till läsaren.
*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although since you are learning C I think that GCC would be wiser option than MSVC compiler. What you actually do now is writing C++ compilable C code.

Comment: In addition to the C++ remark, MS is infamous for their poor support of the C standard. It is very important as a beginner to ensure that you are learning _standard C_ and not some local, non-standard language. `getch()` for example is an old remain from the Borland days, originally found in their conio.h, it is not standard C and has never been. I would advise to use GCC as well. If you like the MS editor, by all means stick to it.

Comment: On the other hand, Visual Studio is the standard native tool that works out-of-the-box for developing on Windows. Trying to use GCC in this environment is another learning experience, just as big a hurdle as learning a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use your favorite function

```
getch();
```

but please do not forget to add

```
#include<conio.h>
```

because the getch() function is inside the conio.h headerfile. You forgot to include the header file for that function.

Comment: Thank you for the intersting answer. I'm new to the libraries and needed to know this. It worked for me using `System("pause")` but now I understand how also `getch()` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

***"I tried using `getch();` but it didn't compile."***
Use `getchar();` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` is the preferred way of pausing the program just before it exits in order to examine the program output. But you cant exit your program by pressing any key though. <kbd>Enter</kbd> is mandatory in the sense that `getchar` returns only when it sees an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

A better alternative on windows to achieve the thing you precisely need is this-

```
system("pause");
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that `getchar()` is found in stdio.h and `system()` in stdlib.h.

Comment: Many thanks for the info guys. I'm learning a lot while reading books on papers on C and C++, I also learn a lot from the practical configuration and actual programming.